# JavaScript: ¿Cómo llamar a método de la clase padre con parámetros?

Tags: javascript, prototipos

El problema es el siguiente: tengo una clase definida como "elemento basico", que tienen el método: draw(where), definida de la siguiente forma:

```
Element.prototype.draw = function(where)
{}
```

Element es mi objeto base. La pregunta es: ¿cómo llamo a este método como parte de un método de una clase hija de "Element", pasándole los parametros?

Estoy intentando hacer algo así:

```
ClaseHija.prototype.draw= function(where)
{
     Element.prototype.draw().call(this);       
}
```

Pero no sé dónde poner el parámetro "where" en la llamada, ¿cómo se hace esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/apply) pasando los argumentos de la función.

De la siguiente forma:

```js
function Element(){};
function ClaseHija(){};

ClaseHija.prototype = new Element();

Element.prototype.draw = function(where)
{
     console.log("draw to " + where);
}

ClaseHija.prototype.draw = function(where)
{
     Element.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);
}

new Element().draw("somewhere");

new ClaseHija().draw("somewhere else");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, la primera consulta que hago y fue hipeercontestada!

Answer (score 3):

Puedes heredar de la clase `Element` por media `prototype` pero en la clase hija no puede haber otro método con el mismo nombre que la clase padre porque la clase hija lo sobrescribiria.

```js
function Element() { }

Element.prototype.draw = function(){
  console.log("Element drawning");
}

function ClaseHija(){ }

ClaseHija.prototype = new Element(); // extendemos de Elemento

ClaseHija.prototype.makeDraw= function(where){
     this.draw(where); // llamamos al metodo draw del objeto Element
} 

var hija = new ClaseHija();
hija.makeDraw();
```

Nota como `ClaseHija` define una funcion llamda `makeDraw` y no `draw`. Si definieramos el metodo `draw` en la clase hija, esta sobreescribira la de la clase `Element`, haciendo imposible llamar el método original:

```js
  function Element() { }

  Element.prototype.draw = function(){
    console.log("Element drawning");
  }

  function ClaseHija(){ }

  ClaseHija.prototype = new Element(); // extendemos de Elemento

  ClaseHija.prototype.draw= function(where){
       this.draw(where); // hara una llamada recursiva 
  } 

  var hija = new ClaseHija();
  //hija.draw(); <- si ejecutuas este metodo, lanza el error callstack exceded debido a que se esta ejecutando a el mismo.
```

Si la clase hija no define un metodo llamado `draw`, entonces no hay necesidad de especificarlo en la hija:

```js
    function Element() { }

    Element.prototype.draw = function(){
      console.log("Element drawning");
    }

    function ClaseHija(){ }

    ClaseHija.prototype = new Element(); // extendemos de Elemento


    var hija = new ClaseHija();
    hija.draw();
```

O envias la referencia del objeto Elemento como parametro al metodo draw de ClaseHija para evitar coliciones:

```js
  function Element() { }

  Element.prototype.draw = function(where){
    console.log("Element drawning");
  }

  function ClaseHija(){ }

  
  ClaseHija.prototype.draw = function(element, where){
    element.draw(where);    
  }

  var hija = new ClaseHija();
  hija.draw(new Element());
```

Comment: muchas gracias por contestar tan rapido, el tema es que necesito llamar    al método igual que la clase padre: 
    ClaseHija.prototype.draw= function (where)
    {cosole.log("algo mas se hace aqui");
    Element.prototype.draw().call(this);
    }

Comment: No. Tienes que llamar el metodo diferente al definido en la clase padre o el metodo sera sobreescrito por la clase hija. Claro, esto siempre y cuando lo hagas por prototype.